# Using apply function to Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to do an emulation of a loan with monthly payments in pandas.

The **credit** column contains amount of money which I borrowed from the bank.

The **debit** column contains amount of money which I payed back to a bank.

The **total** column should contain the amount which is left to pay to a bank. Basically it contains the subtraction result between the credit and debit column).

I was able to write the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

# This function returns the subtraction result of credit and debit
def f(x):
    return (x['credit'] - x['debit'])


df = pd.DataFrame({'credit': [1000, 0, 0, 500],
                   'debit': [0, 100, 200, 0]})

for i in df:
    df['total'] = df.apply(f, axis=1)

print(df)
```

It works (it subtracts the debit from the credit). But it doesn't keep results in the total columns. Please see Actual and Expected results below.

**Actual result**:

```
   credit  debit        total
0    1000      0         1000
1       0    100         -100
2       0    200         -200
3     500      0          500
```

**Expected result**:

```
   credit  debit        total
0    1000      0         1000
1       0    100          900
2       0    200          700
3     500      0         1200
```

Comment: Please feel free to correct this question if I am wrong on something

Comment: The function is working as expected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [cumsum](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
df['total'] = (df.credit - df.debit).cumsum()

print(df)
```

**Output**

```
   credit  debit  total
0    1000      0   1000
1       0    100    900
2       0    200    700
3     500      0   1200
```

Comment: Might be helpful to explain cumsum() also.

Comment: Daniel, thank you. It is short and sweet and works like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need apply here.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'credit': [1000, 0, 0, 500],
                   'debit': [0, 100, 200, 0]})

df['Total'] = (df['credit'] - df['debit']).cumsum()

print(df)
```

Output

```
  credit  debit  Total                                                                                                                                                           
0    1000      0   1000                                                                                                                                                           
1       0    100    900                                                                                                                                                           
2       0    200    700                                                                                                                                                           
3     500      0   1200
```

The reason why apply wasn't working is because apply executes over each row rather than keeping the running total after each subtraction. Passing [cumsum()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html) into the subtraction kill keep the running total to get the desired results.

Comment: Hi, Edeki. Thank you for your answer. It works excellent as well. I apologize that I can't check both answers as better ones. Cheers!